# Possible at all VScode ? option or extenstion to manually color markup words (non syntax)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Abit of a longshot as this is more like a paint program or word/excel stuff and not really related to a programming language/struct syntax.

But is it possible at all to make either VScode do it or an extension to do it so i would be able to mark blocks of text and give them different background colors ?

Reason why i would like it is that i often have the need to be able to specify explanations etc where blocks of color would be a huge help for clarity.

If anyone have any ideas on how this could be done it would be awesome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension: [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight). Can be scoped to language (plaintext here `.txt`):

```json
"highlight.regexes": {
    "(@note)(.+)": {
        "filterLanguageRegex": "plaintext",
        "decorations": [
            {
                "backgroundColor": "#a37acc",
                "color": "#fff"
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "#bd9fda",
            }
        ]
    },
    "(@important)(.+)": {
        "filterLanguageRegex": "plaintext",
        "decorations": [
            {
                "backgroundColor": "#ff3333",
                "color": "#fff"
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "#F07171"
            },


        ]
    },
},
```

You probably don't want to use plain words highlighting. Use something with a special sign before/after, like `@`.

```
@note useful to know
@important everything on fire
```

[image]

Comment: that would be an approach i could use - thanks alot !